# jQuery Cycle Pager producing extra pager links

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle

I am working on a website that has a custom Slider that used jQuery cycle.  For some reason, it doubles up the amount of pager links whilst only cycling the original pages.  So with two slides, it produces markup like this, with only the first two links being active:

```
<div id="pager">
  <a href="#" class="activeSlide">1</a>
  <a href="#" class>2</a>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
</div>
```

The code used to build this, in Wordpress is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[title!=""]').hint();
        $('.slideshow-wrap').cycle({ pager: '#pager' });
    });     
</script>

<div class="home-slider">
    <div class="slideshow-arch">
        <div class="slideshow-wrap">
        <?php
        global $post;
        $tmp_post = $post;
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slideshow', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        $blog2 = get_posts( $args );
        ?>
        <?php foreach($blog2 as $post) : setup_postdata($post);  ?>
            <article <?php post_class('post'); ?>>
                <div class="slideshow-content">
                    <?php $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-slideshow-subtitle', true); $linkThis = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-slideshow-link', true); ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php print $linkThis; ?>"><?php print the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <h3><?php print $subtitle; ?></h3>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <p style="text-align: right;"><a href="<?php print $linkThis; ?>">Find out more &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>

                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )): ?>
                <div class="slideshow-img">
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $image[0]; ?>&w=1100&h=360&zc=1" />
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </article>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="pager"></div>

        <img class="slider-overlay" src='/wp-content/themes/jdr/images/transparent-slideshow.png'>
    </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone shed help some light on why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this making cycle operate on article, and moving the slideshow-content div into the slideshowimg div.